# How to pass value dynamically in (click) = "{{ DynamicFunctionCall }}" in angular HTML Template?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

In an angular HTML template, I am trying to pass the function name dynamically as the value of

```
(click) = "{{dynamicFunc Name}}"
```

but it is giving interpolation error.

Is there any way if we can make it work?

Answer (score 0):

No, this syntax is incorrect. In Angular templates, you can bind to component properties or methods using the following syntax:

```
<button (click)="dynamicFuncName()">Click me</button>
```

You cannot use interpolation syntax {{}} inside the event binding syntax ().

You can use a function inside the interpolation without (click) directive like below. But I don't advise it. İnstead of it, check about Angular Pipe.

```
<div>{{dynamicFuncName()}}</div>
```

Comment: In this syntax <button (click)="dynamicFuncName()">Click me</button> , I have to pass the name of the function from the array.  i.e  <button (click)="tobefetchedfromArray">Click me</button>... how can be pass the function name dynamically ??

Comment: I answered your question below the comment. I hope so solves your problem. If you like to run this code, you can reach https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wcav21?file=src/app/app.component.ts with this link.

Comment: It worked. thankyou! Also related to this I have one more query. Can we pass the entire bind to event function i.e.  '(click)="dynamicFuncName()"' in the array and then use it like you have use in your example ? so that I can define the click event also in array itself

Answer (score 0):

If you wish dynamic functions name on element. Follow this code:

```
<button (click)="this[dynamicFuncNamesArray[0]]()">Click me</button>


 dynamicFuncNamesArray = ['dynamicFuncName'];
  dynamicFuncName() {
    console.log('dynamicFunc');
  }
```